# java bytecode editor?

Tags: java, bytecode

What's a good free bytecode editor? I want an editor, something with a GUI...

I tried jbe-0.1b with no luck (can't save the bytecode changes).

Comment: I just downloaded and tested jbe-0.1b and it worked fine for me. After pressing the `Save method` the class was modified (on disk).

Comment: Yes, it should work but when saving I get a console error and it doesn't save anything... maybe something related to the method having many lines... What I really want is just an alternative

Comment: jbe breaks on methods containing the invokeinterface instruction. It tries to parse the interface method name as Integers with predictable results. It does include the source, so in theory it could be fixed.

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308351/is-there-a-java-classfile-bytecode-editor-to-edit-instructions with altenative answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing decent with a UI, but you can use the Eclipse Bytecode Outline plugin to turn any Java class into ASM code, edit it, and produce the changed class. It's probably the most painless way at the moment.

http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I understand jasmin and jasper are the usual pair used to translate between bytecode and an assemly language representation.

IIRC, Apache BCEL comes with a tool to disassemble class files to code which creates the class file with BCEL.

I've used vi. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure. Have you tried to decompile the class files? I don't know what are you trying to do exactly, but you could first decompile the classes, edit the sources and recompile again.

[JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) is a very good decompiler which can handle pretty ugly bytecode and produce readable sources from it.

Comment: because of dependencies missing and complicated stuff I can't recompile the sources. So I just need to bytecode some stupid strings :)

Comment: If you just need to change the strings, any editor should be fine:-). Seriously, I believe they are stored just as strings there.

Answer (score 0):

To create java bytecode you could use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) which offers also eclipse plugins.

ASM is an all purpose Java bytecode manipulation and analysis framework. It can be used to modify existing classes or dynamically generate classes, directly in binary form.

Comment: ASM isn't really designed for manual editing though.