# Is there a java classfile / bytecode editor to edit instructions?

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiler, bytecode-manipulation, .class-file

Is there a utility (or eclipse plugin) for **editing java class files**?
I'd like to manipulate the bytecode of a java class file without recompiling it nor having a complete buildpath.

**E.g. to rename methods, add/delete instructions, change constants etc.**

The only utilities I found are:

- [classeditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/classeditor/) 
  but it's very limited in functionality (**e.g. renaming of things and manipulating instructions isn't possible**).
- [jbe](http://www.cs.ioc.ee/~ando/jbe/) doesn't save changes (maybe because class verifying fails - before I made any changes, although the class runs perfectly)

  (jbe initially had a classpath issue, adding the class path to the jbe.bat file helped)

Comment: What's wrong with _jbe_? It's Java so it should run anywhere.

Comment: @musikk
An exception is thrown:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ee/ioc/cs/jbe/browser
/BrowserApplication

Comment: an exception is not a crash.  You have a classpath issue.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: jbe had a classpath issue when using the shipped jbe.bat. I altered it, now it runs, but I still cannot use it (see edited text above)

Comment: I generally discard a project if I cannot get the provided get-started-examples to run.  If _that_ doesn't run, then what else doesn't?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: This is one of the reasons why I am asking for other utilities than the above mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java bytecode editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395574/java-bytecode-editor)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not seen any byte code -> byte code frontends, but plenty backends.

I would suggest that you have a look at the many byte code manipulation libraries like [`javassist`](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist) which allow loading byte code, manipulate it, and save it back to disk, and then write a small main that does exactly that.

Answer (score 25):

I use [reJ](http://rejava.sourceforge.net/) for editing class files directly.

It allows you to edit instructions, methods, constant pool, diff classes, and a split view with a hex editor.

It's ridiculously awesome.

Comment: reJ seems to be dead (last release took place in 2007)

Comment: reJ would be awesome if editing worked. I've just tried to insert an "ifne" instruction that requires a parameter, I get a NullPointerException because its graphical user interface remains unfinished, it doesn't allow to pass the expected branch offset. Actually, I would advise to use reJ to display the instructions, Java Decompiler to check whether the changes are understood and a plain hexadecimal editor to edit the class file(s).

Comment: By the way, JByteMod just works, it does what reJ fails to do: https://grax.info/ I've used it to patch JOGL 2.3.2 :)

Answer (score 10):

I wrote an [open source Java assembler and dissasembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) you may find useful.

It lets you disassemble a classfile into human readable assembly, edit it, and then reassemble it into a class. It was originally designed for writing obfuscated crackmes, so there are a lot of obscure features it supports that many other tools don't. If you need any features it doesn't currently support, feel free to contact me and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

Find [this](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries) list of byte code manipulation/code generation libraries helpful?

Comment: I need working tools, I don't have the time to code such a tool by myself (neither with the help of those libraries).