# How to change methods in .class file without recompiling

Tags: java, class, reflection, decompiling

I need to change existing compiled **.class** file. Actually I have even sources of it, but I cannot just change and recompile it because of many dependencies that I don't have.

So I need to change 2 methods. Both them have **void** return type. The first contains just 2 lines that are calls of another methods of the same class, i.e.

```
public void a() {
    System.out.println("a");
}

public void b() {
    System.out.println("b");
}

public void ca() {
    a();
    b();

}
```

And I need to change method **ca** sp that it calls only a() method.

The second method that I need to change contains some logic, but I want to clear it at all, i.e. to have method with empty body that does nothing.

How can I do this?

Comment: But if you don't have dependencies of that class how would you run that class after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the required dependencies, how are you expecting to *use* this code? I would strongly recommend that you devote your time to being able to compile this normally, instead of trying to just change the binary. It's likely to be a better bet in the long run.

Comment: >> how are you expecting to use this code? This class is a part of a big application that we need to change. But all dependencies are located on the customer side and we cannot get them

Comment: @Mikhail: So why don't you have the dependencies, or why can't you get hold of them? Trying to go forward with only part of a working environment really isn't a good idea.

Comment: A further question, how will you test your changes before giving the code to the customer?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and set triggers to every call of ca. Then you can easily block that call and call a instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this question on Java Bytecode editors.

[java bytecode editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395574/java-bytecode-editor)

However, I think Jon Skeet's answer is the one that really applies here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change it in the first place, but even if you did succeed, I wouldn't recommend that. A cleaner solution would be to extend your class and override the implementation of the `ca()` method to call only the `a()` method.

Comment: I cannot do this because this class is a part of application that I cannot re-write to use my new class.

Answer (score 0):

If method `a` is public then the easiest way is to use an aspect ([Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)) and intercept every call to `ca`. Instead of invoking `ca` just invoke `a`.

Comment: This is a good idea but I cannot add aspects to the application that I need to change. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Do not change the app at all. Manipulate it with aspects. If you are not allowed to use aspects then it's a completely other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into reflection? I have limited experience with it, but I'm not sure what you want to do it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javaasist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html) library to modify existing class file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I  had to modify a method in a class file with no source. 
The method was rethrowing the exceptions badly so I had to tweak it.
I have decompiled the class with Classfile Analyzer (http://classfileanalyzer.javaseiten.de/)
I have edited then the resulted file and recompiled it with Jasmine assembler.

Using Apache BCEL you can accomplish the same thing but in a more elegant way - at runtime - not as I have described above at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a java decompiler for opening the class file and edit it and save it.

Here's one good decomp --> http://java.decompiler.free.fr/